# Bash - get basename from loop

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, debian

I am trying to get `basename` from loop but this only returns me `"*"`.

```
FILES=("/home/aaaa/bbbb/*") #Get all folders
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  basename "$f"
done
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Considering any one of answer as solution to your query, does direct

"     ls -1 /home/aaaa/bbbb/     " doesn't lead your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `("/home/aaaa/bbbb/*")`, an array is created with just one literal string `"/home/aaaa/bbbb/*"`.

Instead, get rid of the quotes and simply say:

```
FILES=(/home/aaa/bbb/*)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  basename "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need to create an array and execute your loop like this:

```
for f in /home/aaaa/bbbb/*
do
  # get the basename using pure BASH
  base="${f##*/}"
  echo "base is: $base"
done
```

Comment: This works fine for filenames with whitespace. Pathname expansion occurs after word splitting.

Comment: To return to arrays, `names=(/home/aaaa/bbbb/*); basenames=( "${names[@]##*/}")` works, too. No explicit loop needed.